# Web app to consume rest services and display charts accordingly

Tags: javascript, angular.js, html5

I have been an Angular developer for more than 5-6 months and mostly I learned with my experience. However, recently after submitting code to some competition, I got a feedback that AgularJS best practices were not followed. I need some help understanding irregularities in my code.

**Controller**

```
crossover.controller("rootController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$mdToast', '$mdMedia', '$mdDialog', '$location', '$http', function($scope, $rootScope, $mdToast, $mdMedia, $mdDialog, $location, $http){
    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
    $rootScope.sessionId = null;
    $scope.showPopup = function(ev, template) {
        var useFullScreen = ($mdMedia('sm') || $mdMedia('xs'))  &&     $scope.customFullscreen;
        $mdDialog.show({
          controller: DialogController,
          templateUrl: template,
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
          targetEvent: ev,
          clickOutsideToClose:true,
          fullscreen: useFullScreen
        })
        .then(function(answer) {
            if(answer){
                console.log("Hello");
                $mdToast.show(
                  $mdToast.simple()
                    .textContent('Request Sent!!!')
                    .hideDelay(2000).position('top right')
                );
            }          
        }, function() {
            //user cancelled wanna handle?    
        });
        $scope.$watch(function() {
          return $mdMedia('xs') || $mdMedia('sm');
        }, function(wantsFullScreen) {
          $scope.customFullscreen = (wantsFullScreen === true);
        });
    };
    $scope.logout = function(){            
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
        $rootScope.sessionId = '';
        $location.path("/login");             
        //content type sent is text/json but they are not text/json actually
        //so angular giving error while accepting them.
//        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/logout?sessionid=" + $rootScope.sessionId, {parseJSON: false}).then(function(result){           
//            $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;
//            $rootScope.sessionId = '';
//            $location.path("/login");     
//        });        
    }

}]);

crossover.controller("loginController", ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location){
    $scope.user = {
        'userName' : '',
        'password': ''
    };
    $scope.doLogin = function(){        
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/login?username=" + $scope.user.userName + 
                 "&password=" + $scope.user.password)
            .then(function(res){                
                if(res.data.sessionId == null){
                    console.log("Invalid credentials");
                    alert("Please provide correct credentials");
                }else{
                    $rootScope.sessionId = res.data.sessionId;
                    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;                     
                    $location.path("/dashboard");                    
                }
            });
    }
}]);

crossover.controller("dashboardController", ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope',  function($scope, $location, $rootScope){    
    if($rootScope.isLoggedIn != true){
        $location.path("/login");
    }
    $scope.charts = [{
       'what' : 'Sales Total per Sales Man',
       'where': 'salestotal/salesman'
    }, {
        'what' : 'Sales Total per Month',
        'where': 'salestotal/month'
    },{
        'what': 'Top 5 Sales Order',
        'where': 'top5/order'
    },{
        'what': 'Top 5 Sales Men',
        'where': 'top5/salesman'
    }];
    $scope.goto = function(str){
        $location.path(str);
    }
}]);

crossover.controller("pieController", ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location){
    if($rootScope.isLoggedIn != true){
        $location.path("/login");
    }    
    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.data = [];

    $scope.refresh = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/salesmandata?sessionid=' + $rootScope.sessionId).success(function(result){            
            $scope.labels = [];
            $scope.data = [];
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(obj){                          
                $scope.labels.push(obj[0]);
                $scope.data.push(obj[1]);               
            });
        }); 
    }
    $scope.refresh();
}]);

crossover.controller('barController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location){
    if($rootScope.isLoggedIn != true){
        $location.path("/login");
    }    
    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.data = [[]];
    $scope.series = ['Series A'];    
    $scope.options = { scaleShowVerticalLines: false};    
    $scope.refresh = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/lastyeardata?sessionid=' + $rootScope.sessionId).success(function(result){            
            $scope.labels = [];
            $scope.data = [[]];
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(obj){                          
                $scope.labels.push(obj[0]);
                $scope.data[0].push(obj[1]);               
            });
        }); 
    }
    $scope.refresh();        

}]);

crossover.controller('part3Controller', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location){
    if($rootScope.isLoggedIn != true){
        $location.path("/login");
    }    
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.refresh = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/topsalesorders?sessionid=' + $rootScope.sessionId).success(function(result){            
            $scope.items = [];                
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(obj){
                $scope.items.push(obj);
            });
        }); 
    }
    $scope.refresh();        
}]);

crossover.controller('part4Controller', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location){
    if($rootScope.isLoggedIn != true){
        $location.path("/login");
    }    
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.refresh = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/topsalesmen?sessionid=' + $rootScope.sessionId).success(function(result){            
            $scope.items = [];            
            angular.forEach(result.data, function(obj){
               $scope.items.push({
                   'Name': obj[0],
                   'value': obj[1]
               });
            });
        }).error(function(result){
            alert("some error occurred");
        }); 
    }
    $scope.refresh();            
}]);

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.hide = function() {
    $mdDialog.hide();
  };
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $mdDialog.cancel();
  };
  $scope.send = function(answer) {
    $mdDialog.hide(answer);
  };
}
```

I have shared the [rest of the code](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwpA66UPrnUWaEs1ZFcySEtfRGM&usp=sharing) on Google Drive.

Comment: Straight away, you're using `angular.element` in a `controller`. That alone is a big red flag to me - DOM access never goes in the controller.

Comment: @DanPantry that is standard code from demos on material ui site

Comment: then the material ui site is wrong. [Do not manipulate the DOM in controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#!).

Comment: Ok I will make a note of that...thanks for pointing that out...Please point out others...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading the [John Papa style](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) guide as it's endorsed by the angular team.

Typically - if your controller doesn't have to $watch or $broadcast or do event stuff then you shouldn't really be using $scope. Instead use:

```
var vm = this;
vm.variableA = 'Some value';

vm.getStuff = getStuff;
function getStuff() {...}
```

In a directive definition this can be referred to using `controllerAs`

```
controller: 'MyController',
controllerAs: 'vm'
```

Any functions/variables are then referred to as `vm.whateverItsCalled` in the template.

You could combine the two above to this:

```
controller: 'MyController as vm'
```

Also - did you submit any tests with your code to prove that it works?